# Query scope using orWhere in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2, I have the following query scope on my model:

```
public function scopeInProcess($query) {
    return $query->whereHas(
        'ApplicationStatus', function($query) {
            $query->whereRaw('(name = "New" OR name = "In-process")');
        }
    );
}
```

The above works fine, but I only started using `whereRaw()` because I couldn't get `orWhere()` to work as described in the docs.

As far as I can tell, this should do exactly the same thing as `whereRaw()`:

```
$query->where('name', 'New')->orWhere('name' , 'In-process');
```

It doesn't work, though. It just returns all of the records, including ones with other status names.

Comment: did you add "return" before "$query->where(.....);" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not doing the exact same thing. In your `whereRaw()`, you've wrapped both conditions in parentheses, to group them together. This is what you want. However, the `where()->orWhere()` does not automatically do this.

To get your desired functionality, you need to group your conditions, as you did in the `whereRaw()`. You do this by passing a closure to the `where()` method, like so:

```
public function scopeInProcess($query) {
    return $query->whereHas('ApplicationStatus', function($query) {
        $query->where(function($q) {
            $q->where('name', 'New')->orWhere('name', 'In-process');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and that you for explaining it so clearly!

Comment: @patricus - Can you please try to answer the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031207/laravel-5-2-orwhere-generate-and-in-query ?